# Appending a List of Lists without Dataframe Conversion (GoogleSheets)

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is it possible to append  a ***Single row of a List of Lists directly to GoogleSheets***  without having to go through the hassle of converting it  to a ***Dataframe(+gspread)*** first?

On trying to directly append a list of lists, googlesheet gives ***Invalid Values Error*** .

Append Single Row:

```
 single_row_list = [['21-Apr-2023 15:29:34', '25-Apr-2023', 17624.05, ['17700Call+130456', '17600Put+59182', '17900Call+59049', '17600Call+55447'], [], [], ['16900Put-7724']]] 



 request_Buildup = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=niftyoiBuildup_spreadsheet_id , range=nifty_rangeOiBuildup ,
                                                         valueInputOption=value_input_option,
                                                         insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body={"majorDimension": "ROWS","values" : single_row_list})
request_Buildup.execute()
```

Error :

```
Error :<HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1lz/values/nifty_oiBuildup%21A%3AI:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&alt=json returned "Invalid values[2][3]: list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "17700Call+130456"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "17600Put+59182"
  }.......and so on
```

Comment: From your showing sample value of `single_row_list`, in this case, it is required to flatten the value and create it as a 2-dimensional array. But, from `Is it possible to append a Single row of a List of Lists directly to GoogleSheets without having to go through the hassle of converting it to a Dataframe(+gspread) first?`, you want to directly put your `single_row_list` without converting 2-dimensional array. Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike- Yes, directly append single_row_list without converting to 2-dimensional array

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Yes, directly append single_row_list without converting to 2-dimensional array`, if I found your expected result, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: Its been done in plugins like Gspread ... there should be a way to do this.